# Understanding C++ Virtual Methods of Instances Allocated on the Stack

Tags: c++

For the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
virtual int f(){return 1;}
};
class B : public A{
public:
virtual int f(){return 2;}
};
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    A b=B();
    cout<<b.f()<<endl;
}
```

I expect the number `2` to be printed.  Instead the program prints the number `1`.

Could someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've done is called **slicing.** See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

*Instead, pointers should be used:*

```
A* b = new B();
```

Comment: "_pointers should be used_" If you really want aliasing. Maybe the poster wanted to construct another instance, we just don't know.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). Runtime polymorphism only works through pointer or reference in C++. You can get virtual dispatch with another variable:

```
B b;
A& a = b;
cout << a.f() << endl;
```

Or you can directly assign a *pointer*, like here:

```
A* aptr = new B;
aptr->f();
delete aptr;
```

but here class `B` needs a [virtual destructor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/07/127826.aspx). Though not strictly required in the first case, providing virtual destructor is a general rule for polymorphic types. GCC `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` flag helps you catch this error.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the type of your variable is `A`, and not `B`. The line:

```
A a = B();
```

creates a temporary of type `B` and then copies the `A` subpart of it into `a` that is of type `A`.

To use an object polymorphically you need to handle it through a pointer or reference:

```
int main() {
   B b;
   A &a = b;  // an A reference to the B object
   A *p = &b; // an A pointer to a B object
   a.f();     // will dispatch to B::f
   p->f();    // will dispacth to B::f
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, this is a case of slicing. The type of 'b' is 'A'. It is initialised via the implicitly defined default copy constructor for A:

```
A::A(const A& other);
```

This initialisation is valid because 'B' is derived from 'A'; i.e. it is an 'A'. Try implementing the copy constructor for 'A' explicitly to help understand what is going on.

Note that one practice to avoid this kind of issue is to ensure that all [non-leaf classes are abstract](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/items/item33.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are observing what is called [object slicing](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~hoover/Courses/201/201-New-Notes/lectures/section/slice.htm) in c++. You can alleviate by using a pointer to the base:

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    B b;
    A* a=&b;
    cout<<a->f()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the stack variables into pointers, you will see that you get the correct answer.  This has to do with the fact that b (an instance of A) is allocated on the stack, but remains type A, despite the fact that you copied B() over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;  
class A
{ 
    public: virtual int f()
    {
       return 1;
    } 
};

class B : public A
{ 
public:
    virtual int f()
    {
       return 2;
    } 
};
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{     
      A * b = new B();
      cout << b->f() << endl;
      delete b;
}
```